# How do we implement this ws-security policy in WSO2 ESB 5.0

Tags: wso2, ws-security

We have to implement a proxy service based in a wsdl, and we have to use a security policy like this

```
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="policy">
      <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SigOnly">
         <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
               <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                 <!-- sp:WssX509V3Token10/ --></wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:InitiatorToken>
                     <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                 <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                 <!-- sp:WssX509V3Token10/ --></wsp:Policy>
                           </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:RecipientToken>
                     <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                           <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:Layout>
                     <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                     <sp:ProtectTokens/>
                     <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
               <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                     <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:Wss10>
               <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                  <sp:Body/>
               </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
         </wsp:ExactlyOne>
      </wsp:Policy>
   </localEntry>
```

How can we do? what steps we have to follow to implement it? do we need any rampart configuration??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we have success to call a securre web service using this security policy. Now, the web service needs to call our web service using the same policy, and send signed responds with its public key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the WSO2 Developer Studio IDE for this task...

- Step 1: Create a registry resource project for store your policy.
- Step2: Apply the security policy to your proxy service.
- Step 3: Create a composite application and deploy the proxy and the
  security policy to the WSO2 ESB.

Take a look a this: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am new in wso2, so i have a lot of questions.

Comment: One comment more. How can i sign the message response in the out sequence using the same ws-policy which i use into in sequence??

Comment: how sign the messages the ESB or the backend service? describe the full scenario with client -> esb -> backend and backend-> esb -> client

Comment: Client send request message to proxy service into esb, main sequence process it and update database, then using payload factory we build a message response to send the client. Last message is like ack to the previous message. This ack must go into signed soap message. You note there is no endpoint backend. The proxy service must use a defined wsdl send us by the client. I hope to explaien me right way.

Comment: We have noted that we send • <wsu:Timestamp>
• <ds:signature>, but our client wait a • <wsse:BinarySecurityToken> too.